# 'pattern matching' on Typeable types

Tags: haskell, syntax, types, dynamic-typing

Suppose, for example, we have the following data structure:

```
data Foo = Bool Bool | Int Int | Double Double
```

Now, is there an easier way to do this:

```
foo :: Typeable a => a -> Foo
foo x = maybe (error "i dunno") id $
  liftM Bool   (cast x) `mplus`
  liftM Int    (cast x) `mplus`
  liftM Double (cast x)
```

Has someone thought of making a syntax for pattern matching on *Typeable* types?

Answer (score 6):

Use `typeOf` and guards:

```
foo x
    | tx == typeOf "str" = "string"
    | tx == typeOf True  = "bool"
    | otherwise          = "i dunno"
  where tx = typeOf x
```

Comment: I think this is a good approach. One minor point is that typeOf "str" won't work well in the presence of OverloadedStrings, which is become more common these days.

Comment: There is similar problem with number literals. It also doesn't scale up to situations when you don't have constructors for datatype / they are not pure. You would end up with `(undefined :: Foo)` before too long, which is ugly. Because of this I don't like this solution.

Comment: Typecase should be a tiny bit ugly. It reminds us to go back to programming with real types and stop messing around with all this runtime mushiness.

Answer (score 4):

You can use view patterns here, they are quite handy extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Data

data Foo = Bool Bool | Int Int | Double Double
         deriving (Show)

foo :: Typeable a => a -> Foo
foo (cast -> Just x) = Int x
foo (cast -> Just x) = Bool x
foo (cast -> Just x) = Double x
foo _ = error "i dunno"
```

Results:

```
*Main> :l foo_typeable.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo_typeable.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> foo "123"
*** Exception: i dunno
*Main> foo 1
*** Exception: i dunno
*Main> foo (1 :: Int)
Int 1
*Main> foo (1 :: Integer)
*** Exception: i dunno
*Main> foo (1 :: Double)
Double 1.0
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution!

Answer (score 3):

This version doesn't limit itself to `Bool`, `Int`, or `Double`, but a `String` comes out as `[Char]`.

```
foo :: Typeable a => a -> String
foo = show . typeOf
```

Comment: ... which is reasonable, since `String` is just a type alias for `[Char]`.